# How much Git knowledge do I need to host a site using GitHub pages?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I'd like to host a static site using GitHub Pages. My only issue is that I do not know any Git.

How much Git do I need to know in order to host a site?

Comment: This question is bascially a call for a tutorial on how to host a page on via github pages and hence borderline off-topic

Comment: also github themselves offer a rather straightforward introduction: https://pages.github.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple site with a single developer you really only need to know three git commands:

- `git add` to tell Git to track your changes.
- `git commit` to commit those changes.
- `git push` to send your changes to Github.

If you use [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) you don't even need to know that, use their app instead.

You can even forgeo all that and edit the files on Github's own site, though that could get a bit tedious.

[Github has a walkthrough about how to start using Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Basic knowledge. If you can commit files to your repo and push it back to GitHub, the rest is just web form configuration.

See https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/

Answer (score 0):

Well git is only a version control software. So if you wish to work on this project over multiple computer or with other people then sure learn it. But other than that you will not need Git to write a site.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing basic git commands such as 'add', 'remove', 'status', 'commit' and 'push' will make your life easier, but they are not really required as GitHub offers the chance to upload files by drag-and-drop.
Furthermore, you can view commits and the log online, without "git log"
Thus, the "minimum" amount of commands to know is 0, doesn't mean learning them is pointless, though.